# C# WPF Unable to select row by clicking in first column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I am new into WPF and I have problem as I mentioned in title.
I'm using `ListBox`.
When I click into row in first column. I cannot select value.
It works when I click on border of row.
In second column I have no problems.
[image]

This is how looks `ListBox` and `Grid`. And now how it's look running.
[image]

XAML code below

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="24,45,375,124" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="ProductListView" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" AutomationProperties.IsColumnHeader="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.508,0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2,0,-19,0">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle/>
                <!--
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                -->

            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="350" x:Name="Nazwa_Produktu" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="Cena_w_zl" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PricePerUnit, StringFormat=\{0\} zł}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden Scrollbar seems to be overlapping with your first column, making the items inside unselectable.

I tested with your provided code and removed:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

This solved the issue you have mentioned!
Is there a reason why the hidden scrollbar has to be there?

Comment: What a mistake. Thanks a lot.

I wanted to disable scroll when we have long product name and force seperate product name for two rows. 
I am new into WPF and fronted and I'm trying ugly hacks.
Thanks again :)